# Why is this column always NULL in a LEFT JOIN query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some trouble . I have been writing a SQL query that fetches 5 columns from 2 tables. In a simple join, the column named `CustomerCode` is displayed correctly, but in the below query, it is displayed `NULL`. In fact, I want to select from the two tables with a left join.

This is my query:

```
  select fff.*,CustomerCode,SUBSTRING(( SELECT DISTINCT
                                                RIGHT('0000'
                                                      + LTRIM(RTRIM(CustomerCode)),
                                                      4)
                                                       + '-'
                                        FROM    TatEstelam.dbo.CustomerInfo
                                        WHERE   ltrim(rtrim(CodeMelli))  <> '' and CodeMelli <> '0000000000' AND CODEMELLI  <> '0'  AND  Nationalcode = fff.CodeMelli
                                      FOR
                                        XML PATH('')
                                      ), 0,
                                      LEN(( SELECT DISTINCT
                                                    RIGHT('0000'
                                                      + LTRIM(RTRIM(CustomerCode)),
                                                      4) 
                                                      + '-'
                                            FROM    TatEstelam.dbo.CustomerInfo
                                            WHERE  ltrim(rtrim(CodeMelli))  <> '' and CodeMelli <> '0000000000' AND CODEMELLI  <> '0'  AND  Nationalcode = fff.CodeMelli 
                                          FOR
                                            XML PATH('')
                                          ))) 
                                          AS customerNumber from ( SELECT  NameOutput AS Fullname ,
                shobehNew AS BRANCHNO ,
                ShenaseMelli AS Nationalcode ,
                [CodeMelli],

                CreateDate AS RegisterDate ,


                N'ساها حقوقی' as type
        FROM    TatEstelam.dbo.tblCodeMRequest_0  where CreateDate BETWEEN  '920101' AND '930501'  and CusType = 6) as fff
       LEFT JOIN (select DISTINCT Nationalcode,customercode,NationalID from TatEstelam.dbo.CustomerInfo where InqueryType <> '01' ) ci ON fff.Nationalcode = ci.NationalID and ltrim(rtrim(CodeMelli))  <> '' and CodeMelli <> '0000000000' AND CODEMELLI  <> '0' 
        ORDER BY CODEmELLI
```

but in this query customer code will display :

```
     select * from TatEstelam.dbo.CustomerInfo c right join TatEstelam.dbo.tblCodeMRequest_0 m
         on c.Nationalcode = m.ShenaseMelli
```

Comment: It's difficult analysing that query because (I suspect) there is much in it that does not contribute to the problem you describe (and because we don't see any concrete data). General recommendation: I suggest that you remove everything from the query that does not actually cause the problem (even if it changes the result). Write the simplest query involving a `SELECT CustomerCode` and a `LEFT JOIN` between `tblCodeMRequest_0` and `CustomerInfo`, and see if the problem persists. If not, re-add subqueries, `WHERE` clauses, etc. until the error appears again. Then you will know what causes it.

Comment: Can you try to make a simplified version and maybe add an example of SQL Fiddle?

Comment: can you say clearly ?

Comment: Why don't you post a little bit of sample data from each of the two tables involved, and edit your posted SQL query to remove columns that don't actually impact the question. Setting up a SQL Fiddle would be even better - that's a website (Google it) that allows you to create a sample environment with your table structures and data that other people can use to help correct your code.

Comment: you suggest me to delete this post ?

Comment: NO! There is an `edit` button at the bottom of your post, which you can use to make changes and updates with new information.  I suggest you edit your post to contain more information (like the sample data) in response to requests received in comments.

Comment: Thanks for editing!  The JOIN conditions are different between your two queries, which is why one returns NULL and the other does not.  Go through your table and evaluate each condition one-at-a-time: Do records ever have an InqueryType other than 01?  Is the NationalCode field there always equal to the NationalID field in the CodeRequest table (and why don't you use NationalID from both tables)?  Is CodeMelli always NULL? You know the data exists, but something in your JOIN condition is always evaluating to 'FALSE' and not allowing that data to appear in your result.

Comment: Without seeing the actual data in your tables, nobody on this website can tell you which part of your query is the problem - but if you can follow the debugging instructions, you should be able to identify it for yourself.  If you try without success, you can always edit your post again with legitimate sample data from both of your tables.

Comment: on c.Nationalcode = m.ShenaseMelli and fff.Nationalcode = ci.NationalID are same column . yes codemeli is always null

Comment: thank you very much sir my question was terrible . thnx

Comment: Not a problem here - you were willing to learn and make edits and provide information.  Even a question with an 'obvious' answer isn't bad if you learn from it. There are resources (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that can help you improve, but if you post a clear question, sample data, and show us what code you've tried, than generally we'll be happy to help :) Good luck!